# Find B such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow-3^-}\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+7x+B}=-\infty$

Tags: calculus

Okay so I know that the answer is 12 but I don't understand how to get there. Am I right in thinking that we're going to use l hospitals rule for this? Can someone please guide me and explain to me the process of solving this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow-3}x^2-4=5>0
$$
and in this case it doesn't matter if the limit approaches from right or left.

In order to get infinity in the limit above, $-3$ must be a zero of
$$
x^2+7x+B
$$
So we have to impose $(-3)^2+7(-3)+B=0$ from which we get $B=12$.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! Enjoy your green check!

Comment: Thank you very much Dylan!